# What is the difference between dynamical horizon and apparent horizon?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, event-horizon

The condition for both the dynamical horizon and an apparent horizon is that expansion of outgoing null normal $\theta_l$ = 0 and expansion of ingoing null normal  $\theta_n$ < 0. Then what is the difference between an apparent horizon and a dynamical horizon?

Comment: Any timeslice of a (3-dimensional) DH is a (2-dimensional) AH. So a DH is the "total picture" of the time evolution of an AH. See this paper for details: https://arxiv.org/pdf/gr-qc/0308033.pdf